# Converting Animation data from Maya to DirectX in C++

Tags: directx, animation, maya

I am currently trying to export an animation from Maya and import to a program I am working on. One of the problems I currently have is that when imported, the mesh and animation data looks reversed along the Z-axis. I do know the Maya is right handed where as DirectX is left handed. I was curious if there was a simple solution to this. I was able to convert the mesh just fine, with the help of this web page, http://rastertek.com/dx10tut08.html. But this didn't tell me how to the animation data as well. Any help solving this problem would be awesome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you using to load/play your animation back?